# Battery efficient android widget that updates once a minute

Tags: android, android-widget, android-service, android-alarms

I know this is a possible duplicate, but i havent found a specific answer to this? (there are partial answers on how to force the widget to update every second but its not all i am after...)

1. I need to have a widget that will update once a minute.
2. How to make  a battery&CPU&RAM efficient widget for this purpose? (The data will be fetched from the internet and parsed before showing it to the user(a small amount of data and processing to be done.))
3. **Should i make a Service that runs on BOOT if the user has the widget on screen and have that service schedule an alarm manager that wakes up a service that updates the widget?**

Also i would like to pause this service if the screen is locked or off to save battery...

Answer (score 1):

That's exactly how I did something similar. I created a Service (`IntentService` if you don't need anything complicated) and then register it with the alarm manager.

```
long interval = intervalMinutes * 60 * 1000;
long firstTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();

Intent i = new Intent(ctx, AlarmService.class);
// Use the widget ID to update only one widget at a time.
i.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, id);
PendingIntent mAlarmSender = PendingIntent.getService(ctx, id, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) ctx.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, firstTime, interval, mAlarmSender);
```

being AlarmService.class your Service or IntentService.

For boot event, you can create a `BroadcastReceiver` and manage a `android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED` action where you can register the alarm.

You can register for that event in your `AndroidManifest`:

```
<receiver android:name=".BroadcastReceiverWidget" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: Thanks i implemented that, i would just add that adding BOOT_COMPLETED is not necessary, since onEnabled method of appWidgetProvider is called on boot, so this is a good place to do some starting initialization that will be used for all widgets.